# UPDATE affecting less rows than equivalent SELECT

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

The following query returns 2303 rows:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM cur_analises a
    INNER JOIN cur_materias_subsidiarias ms
    ON ms.materia_id = a.materia_id
    AND ms.subsidiaria_id IN(SELECT id FROM cur_subsidiarias WHERE cliente_id = 134)
    INNER JOIN cur_materias m
    ON m.id = a.materia_id
    INNER JOIN cur_clientes c
    ON c.carga_id = ms.subsidiaria_id
WHERE a.cliente_id = 134;
```

I need to update the `cliente_id` field of all those 2303 rows from table `cur_analises` with the value from `cur_clientes.id`. However, when I try to turn that `SELECT` query into the following `UPDATE`, it only affects 2297 rows, according to MySQL Workbench:

```
UPDATE cur_analises a
    INNER JOIN cur_materias_subsidiarias ms
    ON ms.materia_id = a.materia_id
    AND ms.subsidiaria_id IN(SELECT id FROM cur_subsidiarias WHERE cliente_id = 134)
    INNER JOIN cur_materias m
    ON m.id = a.materia_id
    INNER JOIN cur_clientes c
    ON c.carga_id = ms.subsidiaria_id
SET a.cliente_id = c.id
WHERE a.cliente_id = 134;
```

I have no idea why it's missing 6 rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do six of those rows already have the value you're trying to set?

Comment: No, they are new ids generated by `auto_increment` on the previous query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably not joining on a unique value or set of values at some point in the query causing denormalization of your result set.  Then when you do the update it only updates the rows that actually meet the criteria of the joins for the table aliased as a.  Only you can know what are truly non denormalizing joins in your query and fix them.

Comment: You were right. Turs out the correct number of rows to be updated was 2292, I was off by eleven rows.

Comment: This thing was about to ruin my day, the silent cursing had begun

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar case, the issue was with mysql partitioning. Once we revert partitioning everything is ok again.